# why octave step response doesnt get to the step?

Tags: octave

Got my code here.

```
#! /bin/octave -qf
nn=[0.13785];
dd=[1 14 60 200];
t=0:0.005:5;
[y,t,x]=step(tf(nn,dd), t);
plot(t,y)
pause()
```

Why does octave makes a step of 0.007, instead a step of 1? I think its not octave problem but my understanding of the process

Comment: The `step` function returns the response to a unit step input. The output for a real system may be above or below one or even negative. Your question is more about math / control theory than octave, I think, and is thus probably off-topic for StackOverflow. I'd recommend reading a textbook on the subject or asking a version of this at [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com). This [page](http://mathworks.com/help/control/examples/plotting-system-responses.html) from The MathWorks has other ways to explore your system if that helps and if octave supports those.

Comment: That's because your static gain is `0.13785/200 = 0.0007` approximately. The step response is correct for your transfer function.

Comment: thanks a lot! the problem was the static gain yes